# math for calculating timezone offset at particular instance of utc time since epoch

Tags: datetime, dart, timezone, utc

Is it possible to find (via A mathematical formula) a timezone (or offset) with a given time instance (for example in UTC) measures in millisecond/microseconds etc since January 1, 1970.

`result = getTimeZoneOffset(date.now(), some_Date_before_Or_After_The_date_now);`

how can I fill this method?

For example: In dart language, we can only get offset relative to current timezone and not for others. Like, If I go back in UTC time what will be the offset at that particular time instance.
Please advise.

*P.S. I hope, I am not confusing stuff here.*

Answer (score 2):

Time zones are governed by politics, not math.

You will need an implementation of the [IANA time zone database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database), such as the one provided by the [timezone](https://pub.dev/packages/timezone) Dart package.